# how to animate SVG polyline with snap.svg?

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

I'm creating a simple polyline:

`snapRef = Snap("#svglogo"),`

adding random polyline:

`var test = snapRef.polyline([[0, 0], [30, 0], [30, 30], [0, 30]]);`

but when I try to animate it:

`test.animate({
    points:  [[50, 50], [50, 50], [50, 50], [50, 50]]
}, 100);`

I get the following error:

`snap.svg-min.js:19 Error: <polyline> attribute points: Unexpected end of attribute. Expected number, "22.5".`

(the last number in the error abover varies).

Am I doing something wrong?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: can you try like this: [50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50]

Comment: http://snapsvg.io/docs/#Paper.polyline

Comment: yes, tried that as well, actually before using the format in my example above. neither of those work :(

Comment: and the animation http://snapsvg.io/docs/#Snap.animate "from" and "to" you can insert the arrays